# adding text to the textview from arraylist with coma as seperator in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, textview

i have to show the data on the textview and i am fetching it from arraylist and add coma as seperator between them and if their is nothing in the list it must show not specified and what code i wrote for this is

```
   if (skill.size() != 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < skill.size(); i++) {
                    if (!skill.get(i).getSkillName().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                        tvKeySkills.append(skill.get(i).getSkillName());
                        if (i != skill.size() - 1 && !skill.get(skill.size()-1).getSkillName().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                            tvKeySkills.append(" , ");
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                tvKeySkills.append("Not Specified ");
                tvKeySkills.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_three));
            }
```

now i am facing one problem is that if someone is entering only empty strings it is not showing anything empty textview as it must show not specified and if some data is their in the listview and last 2 index value is empty string it is showing coma at last which it must not show.

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod please check the question before marking it as duplicate. The problem i am facing is totally different from what link you have send.

Comment: can't you validate before allowing empty values, like if user input is empty you can prompt to enter some data.

Comment: also inplace of checking equals with `""` you can use `TextUtils.isEmpty()`

Comment: TextView is empty because you are appending "Not Specified " only if the list is empty. Inside 'for' loop where you are checking if not empty, it's else condition (if empty) is not handled.

Comment: @KaranMer no, data is coming from json so i cant prompt to enter data. i just have to basically check if all the elements in the arraylist contains " " than it must show "not specified".

Comment: @Kaustuv yeah i know it is not handled because the problem is that if array list is of 5-6 elements and assume some are empty like element at index 2 is empty string if i will handle else part of if and will add not specified their than output will be like :  " angular,CSS,not specified,Bootstrap" something like this will happen

Comment: @AnushaMathur: you can still use `TextUtils.isEmpty()` to satisfy your match.

Comment: So you want not specified only if 1.whole list is null or empty OR 2.all the items in list is empty. Anything else (means some content) should appear as comma separated single string in one TextView. Correct?

Comment: @Kaustuv yeah i want show not specified only when whole list is null or empty or all the items in list is empty and if any any element is empty within the list it must skip that element and should not add coma after last element even it is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First handle list is empty or null.

Then for each place in list check for not null and not empty skill name, keep adding it to a local string.

This local string will be starting with `,`. Remove that before setting in text view.

```
String keySkills = "";

if(skill != null && !skill.isEmpty()){
    for (int i = 0; i < skill.size(); i++) {
        if (skill.get(i).getSkillName() != null && !skill.get(i).getSkillName().isEmpty()) {
            keySkills = keySkills+", "+ skill.get(i).getSkillName();
        }
    }

    if(keySkills.isEmpty())
        keySkills = "Not Specified";
}else {
    keySkills = "Not Specified";
}

if(keySkills.equals("Not Specified")
    tvKeySkills.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_three));
else
    keySkills = keySkills.subString(2); // handle initial ',' with a space

tvKeySkills.setText(keySkills);
```